# Cannot set CssClass property in inherited Label / TextBox WebControl

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I have created a very simple custom control:

```
     [assembly: System.Web.UI.TagPrefix("CustomMultiLineTextBox", "evo")]
        public class CustomMultiLineTextBox : 
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
        {

            public override int Rows
            {
                get
                {
                    return 5;
                }
            }

            public override System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode TextMode
            {
                get
                {
                    return System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
                }
            }
    public override string CssClass
            {
                get
                {
                    return "textboxStyle";
                }
                set
                {
//base.CssClass = "textboxStyle";
                    base.CssClass = value;
                }
            }
        }
        }
```

However, when I drop this control onto my aspx page the CssClass does not seem to be applied. The TextMode and Rows property are set correctly.

```
    <evo:CustomMultiLineTextBox ID="txtTrainingNeeds" runat="server">
</evo:CustomMultiLineTextBox>
```

Only if I add CssClass="textboxStyle" to markup will the CssClass be applied.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it doesn't look like you're modifying behavior, only data, I would set the properties to the values you want in the constructor instead of overriding the properties themselves.

```
public CustomMultiLineTextBox()
{
    Rows = 5;
    TextBoxMode = System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
    CssClass = "textboxStyle";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly. Do you know why it has to be done in the contructor and not in the over-ridden properties? (Just so I know in future). Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure why the overridden Rows and TextBoxMode properties worked for you without setting them via markup or elsewhere in the codefile -- AFAIK, they are only returning values and not actually setting anything on the object. CssClass' getter is doing the same -- only returning a literal value and not referencing anything on the object. You need to call CssClass' setter, which you do via CssClass="textboxStyle" in the markup.

The other way to handle this is via setting DefaultValueAttribute on the properties.